# How to output a list of strings into a file with printf

Tags: file, input, printf, ocaml

I aim to write a function to read a string list `persons` with `open_out` and store it in the file `filename`
I tried to iterate over it with List.fold_left and use `printf`, however it is not working.

```
let write_list filename persons =
  let file = open_out filename in 
  let write_person p =
    let rec ite_pres aux acc = List.fold_left (Printf.fprintf file "%s\n" filename )
    List.iter write_person persons;
  close_out
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? That's not a very useful problem description. What actually does happen? And what have you done to try to debug it?

Comment: @glennsl I don't know how to iterate over the whole list while using Printf

Comment: Do you just want to write one string per line?

Comment: @Shawn yes, every string in the list should be written as a line in the file

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to print one line by file `List.iter` is enough:

```
let chan = 
List.iter (Printf.fprintf chan "%s\n") persons
```

With OCaml 4.14 and later version, you can also use `with_open_text` which opens and close the file channel by itself:

```
let write_list filename persons =
  Out_channel.with_open_text filename (fun chan ->
    List.iter (Printf.fprintf chan "%s\n") persons
  )
```

with_

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to mess with folds, or even with the `Printf` module, if all you want to do is write a `string list` to a file, one element per line. For example:

```ml
(* Like print_endline but for arbitrary output channels *)
let output_endline chan s = output_string chan s; output_char chan '\n'

(* Open a file and call f with the output channel as its argument.
 * Note: Available as Out_channel.with_open_text in Ocaml 4.14 and newer *)
let with_open_text filename f =
  let chan = open_out filename in
  try
    f chan; close_out chan
  with x -> close_out chan; raise x

let print_list_to_file filename slst =
  with_open_text filename (function chan -> List.iter (output_endline chan) slst)

let _ = print_list_to_file "output.txt" ["a";"b";"c"]
```

This defines a couple of handy convenience functions, and uses with them `List.iter` to print out the list.